# Como criar uma página principal para minhas bibliotecas do GITHUB?

Tags: github

Geralmente, quando ativamos o `github page` para um determinado package, é gerada uma url para você publicar documentações a respeito de determinada biblioteca no `Github`.

No caso, se minha conta é chamada de `username` e a biblioteca de `lib`, é possível acessar essa página pela seguinte url:

```
  http://username.github.io/lib
```

Para o caso de organizações, segue a mesma regra acima, mas ao invés de usar o nome do usuário, usa-se o nome da organização.

Porém, agora, eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de criar uma página principal para esse domínio da conta do `github`. Pois atualmente, se eu acessar `http://username.github.io`, consta como `404 - página não encontrada`.

Como criar uma raiz para esse domínio especial do Github?

É possível fazer isso, ou isso domínio só serve para cada biblioteca?

Comment: Legal. Sempre tive curiosidade de de como fazer isso ***=)***

Comment: Que bom saber que ajudou. Dá uma olhada na página do nosso [phplegends.github.io](http://phplegends.github.io/)

Comment: Queria entender qual é o problema com a minha pergunta para receber negativo. É sempre bem-vindo deixar comentários para que possamos melhorar a qualidade da pergunta e do site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Github Pages

Você está falando do `Github Pages`. No Github, é possível sim criar a página principal (na raiz do domínio) do sua conta.

Você deve prestar bastante atenção, pois você precisa fazer essa operação manualmente.

Primeiramente, você deverá criar um novo repositório. Pode ser na sua conta ou na conta da organização que você criou no `Github`. Esse repositório deverá seguir a seguinte regra:

Ter o nome `<nome_do_usuario_ou_organizacao>.github.io`.
Isso deve ser seguido à risca para dar certo. Por exemplo, se você tem uma conta chamada `sou-o-goku` o repositório deverá ter o nome de `sou-o-goku.github.io`

Assim, ao terminar essa operação, basta você fazer o primeiro `git pull` para o branch `master`, e você vera sua página do Github funcionando.

Exemplo:

```
 git init
 echo "Minha página inicial" > index.html
 git add .
 git commit -am "Meu primeiro commit"
 git push -u origin master
```

Depois disso, basta acessar a url `http://minha-conta-github.github.io` para conferir se deu tudo certo.

**Nota**: Não encontrei nada em português a respeito do assunto, por isso resolvi fazer esse post.

Referências:

- [Github Pages - Inglês](https://pages.github.com/)

Comment: Consegui fazer isso.

Comment: Deixa eu fazer uma pergunta. O repositório é público, alguém pode zuar meu repositório dando uns `push` ?

Comment: Não. O repositório é público para visualização. Somente quem tiver a sua private key ou então no mesmo organization que você é que pode "fuçar" no repo.